# Controller function not called when user isn't an administrator

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have the following code but my controller function is not being called for users who don't have a role of "Admin". Can anyone explain where I am going wrong?
To clarify, for users where they are in the role "Admin" it works fine, for all others the controller function is not called.

VIEW:

```
function acceptTerms() {        
    var userName = '@Html.ValueFor(m => m.UserName)';

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("UpdateUserConnects", "User")',
        data: JSON.stringify({ userName: userName }),            
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {               
            if (data == "Failed") {
                alert("failed");
            }
            else {
                var wnd = $("#wndTerms").data("kendoWindow");
                wnd.close();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '@Url.Action("AcceptTerms", "Account")',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (data) {
                        window.location.href = data
                    }
               });
            }
        }
    });

}
```

CONTROLLER:

```
 [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public String UpdateUserConnects(string userName)
    {
        try
        {
            UsersService usersService = new UsersService();
            Users user = usersService.GetUserByUsername(userName);
            if (user != null) {
                user.previouslyConnected = true;
                usersService.UpdateUser(user);
            }               
        }
        catch (Exception e) {  
            return "Failed";
        }
        return "Success";
    }
```

Comment: Any attributes on controller?

Comment: +1 for controller attributes. Also by "not called", you are not mentioning what is being called instead. Does it give a 404? Fall to another method?

Comment: I'm unsure what you mean by attributes so this might be the issue? By not called I mean the controller function isn't entered and it falls past the Ajax function and carries on through the code.

Comment: For example `[Authorize(Roles="Admin")]` on controller allow only admin to execute actions.

Comment: Thanks web developer, I had misread the above and only checked the function attributes. Finally checked the controller attribute and it had [Authorize] which I believe defaults to only allowing the "Admin" role as you explain. Thanks very much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that discovers this later:

CONTROLLER:

```
[Authorize]
public class UserController : BaseController {

    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public String UpdateUserConnects(string userName)
    {
       try
       {
           UsersService usersService = new UsersService();
           Users user = usersService.GetUserByUsername(userName);
           if (user != null) {
               user.previouslyConnected = true;
               usersService.UpdateUser(user);
           }               
       }
       catch (Exception e) {  
           return "Failed";
    }
    return "Success";
}
```

The issue was [Authorize] at the top of the page which only allows people with a role of "Admin" by default to access the functions in the controller.

To allow all users for a specific function use [AllowAnonymous] as an attribute for that function only.

To allow other role names use [Authorize(Roles = "OtherRole")]